# Unable to read RFID data from RDM6300 using Raspberry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid

I'm following these 2 similar guides to read RFID data using my module/pi.

- https://www.lancegrover.com/rfid-rdm6300-em4100-and-raspberry-pi/
- https://behindthesciences.com/electronics/raspberry-pi-rfid-tag-reader/

My code is getting stuck as I try to *read* data from serial. Specifically this:

```
PortRF = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0',9600)
read_byte = PortRF.read()
```

I presume it's because I'm wiring completely wrong

## Their Suggested Wiring

Between the two sites, they suggest the two following wiring setups. I do not have a leveler.

[image]
[image]

## My Attempted Wiring

I'm not totally sure if I'm doing this right, but here is my current wiring:
[image]

## Python Code

```
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

Tag1 = str('0000000C000C')
Tag2 = str('0000000C080C')
Tag3 = str('0000000C010C')
Tag4 = str('0000000C090C')
Tag5 = str('0000000C0A0C')
Tag6 = str('0000000C0D0C')
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(23,False)
GPIO.output(24,False)
PortRF = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0',9600)
PortRF.reset_input_buffer()
while True:
    ID = ""
    read_byte = PortRF.read()
    if read_byte=="\x02":
        for Counter in range(12):
            read_byte=PortRF.read()
            ID = ID + str(read_byte)
            print hex(ord( read_byte))
        print ID
        if ID == Tag1:
            print "White - Ashoka"
            GPIO.output(23,True)
            GPIO.output(24,False)
            PortRF.reset_input_buffer()
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(23,False)
        elif ID == Tag2:
            print "White - Chirutt"
            GPIO.output(23,True)
            GPIO.output(24,False)
            PortRF.reset_input_buffer()
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(23,False)
        elif ID == Tag3:
            print "Red - Vader"
            GPIO.output(23,True)
            GPIO.output(24,False)
            PortRF.reset_input_buffer()
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(23,False)
        else:
            GPIO.output(23,False)
            print "Access Denied"
            GPIO.output(24,True)
            PortRF.reset_input_buffer()
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(24,False)
```

Comment: Did you maybe find any other issues here? I am following the same tutorials and have everything wired up (with the power wire you were missing). The code runs until read_byte = PortRF.read() and then does nothing. The reader has the green light on but goes not acknowledge any tags or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but you are missing the power wire for the RFID module, the orange wire in the top diagram...
And you would need a level shifter to avoid messing your PI...